# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException when multiple datasources in Spring Boot and Mybatis project

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

When configuring multiple datasources in Spring Boot and Mybatis project, following Exception occurs:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager'
>   available: expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   primaryTx,secondTx    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1041)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:345)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:384)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>   ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.findByDomain(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

start of project

```
@SpringBootApplication( exclude = {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class
})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class BookSystemApplication {
}
```

datasource configuration

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.primary")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.second")
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

Transaction

```
@Configuration
public class TransactionConfig {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("primaryDataSource")
    private DataSource primary;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("secondDataSource")
    private DataSource second;

    @Bean(name="primaryTx")
    public PlatformTransactionManager primaryTransaction() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(primary);
    }

    @Bean(name="secondTx")
    public PlatformTransactionManager secondTransaction() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(second);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are defining two `beans` as `datasource` and two beans as `TransactionManager` but you didn't specify which one of them is the `primary` one, *this won't work because **`Spring` needs one `datasource` bean and one `TransactionManager` bean to be defined as primary** if more than one are defined*.

What you should do here is to define, one of your datasources `beans` and one of your TransactionManager `beans` as `Primary`, so that Spring can run correctly, to do so you will need to use **`@Primary` annotation**.

```
@Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.primary")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Please refer to [the Spring's **Configure two datasources** section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-two-datasources) from the Documentation.

Comment: I add @Primary as you suggest, but nothing changes. exception is "NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: primaryTx,secondTx". How can I debug?

Comment: @Hel Do you adde `@Pimary` to the `primaryTx` bean as well? That's what's especially causing the problem.

Comment: I add `@Primary` to the `primaryTx`, but a new exception occurs:"org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): bookSystem.mapper.UserMapper.findByDomain". But MyBatis works well when only one datasource exists. I don't change anything else regarding MyBatis configuration.

Comment: Well, **your first issue is resolved and this is another completely different problem**, you will need to ask a new question, posting all relevant code of `findByDomain()`.

Comment: But `findByDomain()` works well when only one dataSource exists. I think it's related to multiple dataSources. Details will lose if open another question. Is it ok to add this new problem in this question?

Comment: Yes you can, but this will make it ambiguis for futur users, the best would be to have this as a seperate question.

Comment: I've posted a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320198/bindingexception-occurs-when-multiple-datasources-is-configured-in-spring-boot-a

Comment: @Hel Cool, I hope you can find a suitable solution and you can also refer to this question, so people can see what you didi so far to get this. Unfortunately, Ican't help with this new problem, it's out of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

First,thanks √ answer,it solved my problem perfectly.

And I can offer another way of thinking.Unnecessary `@Primary` to someone,you can define like `@Transactional("primaryTx")` in your service.

like this:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional("primaryTx")
    public Test update() {
        Test entity = new Test();
        entity.setId(1L);
        entity.setPhone("19900000050");
        return testRepository.save(entity);
    }
```